# How to save and reload a complex linearlayout as fast as possible?

Tags: android, layout

In my application every time that user presses a button a complex LinearLayout must be created programmatically and then displayed.

The layout takes several seconds to be constructed. To prevent the user waiting each time he/she presses the button I have created the complex layout only once and then saved it into a global LinearLayout variable, then I keep setting the current layout to it by calling the setContentView () function whenever the user needs to be directed to this layout

Everything works ok, but I feel like my method is kinda hackish and I wonder maybe there is another way to accomplish this task:

To save a complex heavy layout and reuse it in a activity or fragment.

Thank you.

Comment: This probably isn't the type of solution you are looking for but... the Android dev guide recommends replacing complex nested layouts with relative layouts, and otherwise rewriting/reorganizing things to limit the depth of the hierarchy. http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html

Comment: Yes I am aware of that link. The RelativeLayout won't do. as the delay in my complex layout is related to loading of images into a ListView which is part of the layout. My question is how to handle the situation when our layout takes time be constructed/inflated. For now I just construct and hold it into memory. Maybe that is actually the right way to go.

Comment: The approach you've taken doesn't seem unreasonable to me. If you can't optimize the layout to load quickly, I guess the next best thing is to avoid superfluous loading. What do these images look like? I guess a potential hack would be to load a static placeholder image when inflating the ListView - and then coming by later (with an AsyncTask) and loading the actual images. Sorry I'm not much help.

Comment: Thanks for affirmation so it seems I am on the right track. The method you are referring to is called "Lazy Loading" of Images and the thing is that my app is a POS and the cashier can not wait for images to be loaded in the systems' leisure time. The response must be immediate. anyway thanks again for your comments.